# Cannot convert json result into struct

Tags: ios, json, swift, struct

I have an API returning something like:

```
{
elements:[{
    name = "user1",
    details =     {
        phone = "0033612345678"
    }
},
{
    name = "user2",
    details =     {
        phone = "0033612346612"
    }
},
{
    name = "test3"
}]
}
```

details key is not present in each element

I have defined an ElementModel.swift file and I’d like to create an ElementModel instance for each element of the elements array.

```
import Foundation

struct ElementModel {
    var name:String
    var phone:String
}
```

In order to get the name and phone value, I've created the following function, called when a request is correctly performed (using delagation)

```
func getRequestSucceed(results: NSDictionary) {
    println("getRequestSucceed")

    // Loop through list of elements
    let elementsArray = results["elements"] as NSArray
    var elementsTmpArray:[ElementModel] = []

    // Convert each result into Element object
    for var i=0;i<elementsArray.count;i++
    {
        // Get NSDictionary from each element
        let element = elementArray[i] as NSDictionary

        // Create Element object with parameters from dictionary
        var name = element["name"] as String
        var phone:String = ""

        // If details key exists, get phone attribute
        if let details = element["details"] as? NSDictionary {
            println(details["phone"])    // Phone number is correctly displayed
            phone = details["phone"] as String  // Simulator crash occurs the first time
        } else {
            println("Not defined")
        }

        // Create element model with name and phone
        var t = ElementModel(name: name, phone: phone)
        elementsTmpArray.append(t)
    }

    // Update table view
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.elements = elementsTmpArray
        self.elementsTableView!.reloadData()
    })
}
```

This approach does not work, seems like the details["phone"] cannot be retrieved that way. I'm very new to swift and not really familiar with Optional. Just wondering if Optional play a part in this problem.
Any idea ?

Comment: Please, add a comment when downvoting the question so it can help to understand why the question is bad or else.

Comment: I always hated the Downvote Drive-Bys...

And I had a similar problem to yours. to fix it I had to hard code the first object which constains an array of data like yours which you call ["Elements"] but wrongly enoough, if you change that yo [0] I assure sure it might work. At least it did for me. I think is a bug with Swift.

Comment: Btw forgot to ask do you even enter your For Loop when you debug it? is the Array  let elementsArray = results["elements"] as NSArray shows as nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 details["phone"]
```

If `details` is  dictionary, the type of the above subscript expression is an optional (dictionaries return nil if there is no element corresponding to the subscript) and so it cannot be cast as a string.  You'll need to unwrap the result before the cast to `String`

Comment: phone = details["phone"]! as String gives me the same crash.

Comment: @Luc `details["phone"] as String?` should work, returning an optional string. Note that you need to save the value into an optional because it obviously can be `nil`. You can't convert it to non-optional.

Comment: @Luc You need to check that the object returned is one that can be cast as String.